# android system class compilation

Tags: java, android, compiler-construction, dalvik

The bytecode for system classes like `android.os.Looper` is simply a stub. For example, `android.os.Looper.loop()` from `android.jar` contains the following bytecode:

```
public static final void loop();
  Code:
   0:   new     #2; //class java/lang/RuntimeException
   3:   dup
   4:   ldc     #3; //String Stub!
   6:   invokespecial   #4; //Method java/lang/RuntimeException."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   9:   athrow
```

But in AOSP, I can see the real source code that performs message dispatch (see `AOSP_ROOT/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/Looper.java`). So how is this class handled exactly by the android system? Is the real code patched in when compiling the system `android.jar` into dex file or does it happen at run-time within the Dalvik VM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `android.jar` which you compile your code against contains only public classes with public (constant) fields and public methods, but all of those methods contain no implementation. All methods with a return type other that `void` throw the "Stub!" `RuntimeException`.

A runtime library with a real implementation is linked with your application only in a phone device or in an emulator.

Comment: Do you mean that none of the classes in android.jar contains real code, and it only has a bunch of stubs to make javac happy? Where can I find the run-time library (both source code and bytecode)?

Comment: Yes, it's just a mock jar to to satisfy your compile time dependency on the android API. As far as I know, you cannot get a working jar without a real Android device or emulator, because it relies on some native functionality.

Comment: As for the source, you can browse it for example here: http://grepcode.com/project/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/ or you can simply download it through the Android SDK Manager in Eclipse. It's under the API15 node, but it works with any older API version installed.